# Is there a virtual machine that supports drag and drop between Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines

I know Virtual PC does it Windows-Windows, but I'm not sure it supports Windows as host, Linux as guest (my scenario) - and anyway Virtual PC isn't an option for me since I'm running Win7 and my processor doesn't have virtualization technologies.

Is there any way to do this? A simple file drag and drop suffices. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Drag and drop of what? You didn't specify...I assume you mean files?

Comment: @davr Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox supports shared folders. So you can setup a shared folder between both Host and Guest OSes and do "drag-n-drop" files between the OSes. I haven't used it on VirtualBox, but I've done a similar "shared folder" setup in VMWare Fusion. It shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Comment: To specifically answer your question in using Virtual PC (I'm not sure which version), here's a KB article straight from MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825086

Answer (score 1):

I don't know other VM but VirtualBox supports drag-n-drop between Linux and Windows through the Guest Additions component.

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried it (VirtualBox 3.0.2; Ubuntu 9.04) and... nothing =/

Comment: I suspect what HD means is that you setup your host to have shared folders and access them through the 'network' on the virtual machine. It's like windows networking or samba, but without having to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

**Not really** because I belive the virtualization types are different. What you can do on linux is:

1. Mount the disk image (if it is a raw disk image like QEmu's) using the loopback interface
2. Use VMPlayer with the supporting tool (i think it is a perl script) to mount the VMware disk

Although this is all Linux to Linux stuff (re-reading the question) but it might provide some fruit looking into the tools supporting the hypervisor.

I would recommend using QEmu and then using SSH to mount the drive over the internal network, this way you wont get into trouble with **locking** and so on when double mounting a virtual device.

You could also use **SMB** to mount the Linux drive on Windows and vice-versa.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try xVM Virtual Box from Sun Microsystems. One of my friends had shown it to me few months back. It supports drag and drop along with many-many other good features like you can run programs and they run as if they are running in host OS, ie you can minimize, maximize, rotate between guest and host GUI programs. It was also emulating graphics card pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS remember to install the guest additions since they allow the guest to communicate with the host.  This includes moving files, sharing clipboard etc.